# Error in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a SQLite, I added 4 columns into my table, but when adding the fifth column "productadd" cannot not be found. What's the problem here? Sorry, I'm really new to sqlite

Below is my DatabaseHelper class

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists producttable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + " productidno"
                + " TEXT ,"
                + " productname"
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productprice" 
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productdest" 
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productadd"
                +" TEXT);");
```

My logcat:

```
 07-28 15:38:49.460: I/Database(382): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table producttable has no column named productadd
07-28 15:38:49.492: E/Database(382): Error inserting productadd=hope productidno=this productdest=and productprice=me productname=is
07-28 15:38:49.492: E/Database(382): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table producttable has no column named productadd: , while compiling: INSERT INTO producttable(productadd, productidno, productdest, productprice, productname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
07-28 15:38:55.401: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
```

Comment: no space betweeen productprice and TEXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists producttable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + " productidno"
                + " TEXT ,"
                + " productname"
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productprice" 
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productdest"
                +" TEXT)");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing space here:

```
+ "productprice" 
   + "TEXT,"
```

Change to :

```
+ "productprice " 
                + "TEXT,"
```